# order of column values in select from scalar type collection

Tags: arrays, oracle, collections

If I have :

```sql
create type tvn as table of number;

select column_value from table(tvn(1,9,27,3,7))
```

Should Oracle return values in the order exactly matching they appear in collection constructor? I mean should it be always:

```
1
9
27
3
7
```

?

Answer (score 1):

No SQL output has a guaranteed order unless you add ORDER BY.  It *might* come back in order 99 times out of 100, but without the ORDER BY, there are no guarantees.

The most common counterexample is running a statement in parallel.

Comment: Thanks, Connor!
So, what should I do? Maybe I need to create a pipelined function?

Comment: @AndrewKlimov - Why do you need the results to be sorted and where is the collection coming from?  You could add an `order by case column_value when 1 then 1 when 9 then 2 when 27 then 3...` that just replicates the data in the collection.  You could create a collection of objects that have a `value` and a `sort_order` attribute and then sort on the `sort_order`.  But I'm not sure if either of those options actually solve the real problem you have.